# How to copy a rect from movieclip to a shape?

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to copy an area from movieclip to a shape graphics, is this possible?

Also, whats the recommended way to clear a bitmapdata?

Comment: what do you mean by clear:) and what do you mean an area:)

Comment: to clear all pixels on it, and make it as newly created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this

```
  //go to target frame
  mc.gotoAndStop(1);

  //the area you want to draw
  var area:Rectange = new Rectange(50, 60, 100, 200);

  if (mc.width != 0 && mc.height != 0) {

       //draw the mc on the target frame
       var temp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height, true, 0x00000000);
       temp.draw(mc);

       //target area bitmapdata
       var targetBD:BitmapData = new Bitmapdata(area.width, area.height, true, 0x00000000);

       targetBD.copyPixels(temp, area, new Point(0, 0));

       //draw to shape
       shape.graphics.beginBitmapFill(targetBD);
       shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, area.width, area.height);
       shape.graphics.endFill();
  }
```

You can call [dispose](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#dispose%28%29) method on BitmapData to clean a bitmapdata, it will Frees memory that is used to store the BitmapData object.

Comment: dispose will not make it as newly created but destroys it and may cause unnececerry garbage collection - if you need to reuse "canvas" you may wish to use `myBitmapData.fillRect(myBitmapData.rect, INIT_COLOR);` where INIT_COLOR is the same value as used when creating bitmap or anything you want to use as background of your canvas.

Comment: @Lukasz I think his meaning of clear is to free the memory so I suggest him to use dispose function. And I usually use bitmapdata for bitmap and in most case the bitmapdata won't be changed, so just call bitmap.bitmapdata = null.